# How to verify an input field using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

How can I verify that the contact number a user inputs in the contact form is in fact numbers and they are at least 10 numbers? Meaning I want the input field only accept 10 numbers or more and also accept the plus (+) sign. At the moment the php verifies that the all fields are completed and the email correct.

here is the html code:

```
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form id="contact-form" action="sendmail.php" method="post" title="Contact Form" role="form">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name">Full name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name..." class="contact-name" id="contact-name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="contact-email" id="contact-email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-number">Contact number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="number" class="active" id="contact-number" placeholder="Your contact number...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-message">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message..." class="contact-message" id="contact-message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default sketchFlowPrint" id="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
          </div>
```

here is the php code:

```
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
    return preg_match('|^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$|i', $email);
};

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'example@gmail.com';

    $clientName = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $number = addslashes(trim($_POST['number']));
    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));

    $subject = 'Query from My Domain';

    $sendMessage = 'Hi' . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= $message . "\n\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'From: ' . $clientName . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Email: ' . $clientEmail . "\n";
    $sendMessage .= 'Contact number: ' . $number . "\n";

    $array = array();
    $array['nameMessage'] = '';
    $array['emailMessage'] = '';
    $array['numberMessage'] = '';
    $array['messageMessage'] = '';

    if($clientName == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Please enter your full name.';
    }
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Please insert a valid email address.';
    }
    if($number == '') {
        $array['numberMessage'] = 'Please enter a valid contact number.';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Please enter your message.';
    }
    if($clientName != '' && isEmail($clientEmail) && $message != '') {
    // Send email
    $headers = "From: " . $clientName . ' <' . $clientEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;".PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= " boundary=\"boundary_sdfsfsdfs345345sfsgs\"";
    mail($emailTo, $subject, $sendMessage, $headers);
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

}   else {
        header ('location: index.html#contact');
}

?>
```

here is the jQuery:

```
// Contact form 
$('.contact-form form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var nameLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-name"]');
    var emailLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-email"]');
    var numberLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-number"]');
    var messageLabel = form.find('label[for="contact-message"]');

    nameLabel.html('Full name');
    emailLabel.html('Email');
    numberLabel.html('Contact number');
    messageLabel.html('Message');

    var postdata = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sendmail.php',
        data: postdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.nameMessage !== '') {
                nameLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.nameMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.emailMessage !== '') {
                emailLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.emailMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.numberMessage !== '') {
                numberLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.numberMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.messageMessage !== '') {
                messageLabel.append(' - <span class="red error-label"> ' + json.messageMessage + '</span>');
            }
            if(json.nameMessage === '' && json.emailMessage === '' && json.numberMessage === '' && json.messageMessage === '') {
                form.fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    form.parent('.contact-form').append('<h2 class="text-center"><span class="orange">Thanks for contacting us!</span> We will get back to you very soon.</h2>');
                });
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: "10 digits". 10 numbers would be "13 2345234 99 83 etc...".

Comment: You should really use PHP's [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`-filter to validate email addresses. Your current regex validates incorrectly. It thinks `1@1.11` is a valid email address, for example.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware. I am currently using the FLITER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the `+` needs to be the first character (international phone numbers)?

Then this should do it:

```
if (!preg_match('/^(\+?)+([0-9]{10,})$/', $number)) {
    $array['numberMessage'] = 'Please enter a valid contact number.'
}
```

The plus sign is optional. If it should be required, just remove the `?` after the plus sign in the expression.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does exactly what I wanted. And yes the + is optional and is for international phone numbers.

Comment: Feel free to check it as answered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the length is less than 10 or see if the input differs from the filtered input (+ and digits removed).

```
<?php
function valid_tel($in) {
    $valid = true;
    if(strlen($in) < 10 || $in !== preg_replace('@[^0-9+]@','', $in)) {
        $valid = false;
    }

    return $valid;
}
var_dump(valid_tel(''));
var_dump(valid_tel('01234'));
var_dump(valid_tel('01234567890')); // 11 long
var_dump(valid_tel('+012345678')); // 10 inc +
var_dump(valid_tel('+0123456'));
var_dump(valid_tel('0123456xyz7890'));
```

Output:

```
boolean false
boolean false
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
boolean false
```